# get single_product_summary on front-page by id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show the summary of a single product on the front-page of my WordPress/WooCommerce Template. So on the front-page.php i want to use the following action:

```
 do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

How can i reference this to the product id with the product-id 150?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of Woo actions work based on global $product variable.
So you can try something like this:

```
global $product;

//first check if the object already exists and store its original value
$reserve_product='';
if(!empty($product))$reserve_product=$product;

//now change global $product value to the desired one
$product=wc_get_product(150);

do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );

//return the previous value
$product=$reserve_product;
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the single product summary please use this code

```
//as you register a custom hook called woocommerce_single_product_summary
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'get_product_summary')

function get_product_summary(){
   $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
   
   if($product){
      $product_details = $product->get_data();

      //for full summary
      $product_full_description  = $product_details['description'];
   
      //for short summary
      $product_short_description = $product_details['short_description'];
      echo '<p>'.$product_short_description '</p>';
   }
}
```